# Bihistogram in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm attempting to create a [bihistogram](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/bihistog.htm) in Tableau and running into trouble getting the formatting right. I was able to create a dual axis chart from the two sets of bins I want to compare and dropped in two measures, the count of records in each bin and the sum of a calculated field that contained just `-1`.
That gets the reflected look I want but both measures show up on both axes of the chart. I'd like to be able to specify that one of the measures should only be shown on one axis and the other measure on the other axis. Is this possible?

The data is structured as follows:

| Expected Duration | Actual Duration | Expected Duration (Bins)  | Actual Duration (Bins) |

Comment: post sample data

Comment: If you mean not to see the axis on one side, you may do this by unticking "Show Header" on the right click menu of the axis. Otherwise sharing some sample data and/or the .twbx containing sample data with what you have done so far would be helpful as @alex-blakemore mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain how this is done via reversing the AXIS

1. **Your shelf would look like this -**

[image: Header]

---

2. **This will result in this -** 
   [image: 2nd]

---

3. **Edit the axis**

[image: Edit Axis]

---

4. **and check the Reversed tick**

[image]

---

5. **The result image will lead to bihistograms**
   [image: BIhistogram]

If you need the TWBX file, let me know I can upload it somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is structured in single rows and I want to compare the distribution of two of the columns, so this method doesn't seem like it would work (see edited original question for structure example).

Comment: @AndrewS it'll be really great if you can share some sample data and expected output(a rough figure/screenshot)

Comment: My twbx had single column named `Population`. I created two new calculated fields as `Male` and `Female`. You can try that

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is options to change what you needed, just right click on any of the axis and you will get the option.